# Выборка записей со значением больше среднего по группе. ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос

Есть таблица студенты со столбцами имя, группа, балл.

Нужно вывести тех студентов у которых балл больше среднего по их группе.

Пробовал так:

```
select
  stud.name, stud.bal
from
  stud,
  (
    select gruppa, avg(stud.bal) as sred_bal
    from stud
    group by stud.gruppa
  ) as B 
Where stud.gruppa = B.gruppa and stud.bal> B.sred_bal
```

выдает ошибку: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Подскажите, как поправить запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка возникает так как псевдоним таблицы задается без `AS`:

```
...
) B   --убрали AS
...
```

Можно также прописать `JOIN` явно и задать осмысленное название для выборки:

```
select stud.name, stud.bal
  from stud
  join (select gruppa, avg(stud.bal) as sred_bal
          from stud
         group by stud.gruppa) stud_avg
    on stud.gruppa = stud_avg.gruppa
where stud.bal > stud_avg.sred_bal
```

[Демонстрация на SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd91b/4)

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю, что в современном Oracle (так же как и в многих других SQL-серверах) поддерживаются [Аналитические функции](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) (еще их называют оконными), которые позволяют выполнять те же действия, не используя второго обращения к той же таблице. Их основное назначение - вернуть результат для группы, без группировки всех данных в запросе:

```
select name, bal
  from (
    select name, bal,
           avg(bal) over(partition by gruppa) as sred_bal
           -- В строке каждого студента показать так же средний бал для gruppa
      from stud
  ) B
 where bal > sred_bal
```